# GetValue, How to handle null values into a Linq sentence

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having problems exporting an entity to excel.

I have this Linq:

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = FieldsToExport(EntitySet.AsQueryable());
int iCols = props.Count();

foreach (var Entity in EntitySet)
{
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, iCols)
        .Select(ii => props[ii].GetValue(Entity)
                                .HandleNullProps()
        );

    // .... write in the sheet
}
```

My problem is when the [ii] property of my entity has a null value,  it is throwing a null exception even if HandleNullProps() is filtering it..

Here is my HandleNullProps()

```
public static object HandleNullProps(this object s)
{
    if (s == null)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with `Ternary` you could assign a value to `Entity` before your var values something like `var tmpEntity = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Entity) ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : Entity;`

Comment: why don't you just replace the select statement with something like this: .Select(ii => props[ii]  == null ? string.empty : props[ii].GetValue(Entity)
        );

Comment: Yep I'm familiar with it, but how can I do to apply it into a Linq?, some of my entities has hundreds of fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `props[ii]` is null, then calling `GetValue(Entity)` will cause a `NullReferenceException`

your `handleNullProps` method is not even reached - the exception is thrown before that

update your select to something like this

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, iCols).Select(ii => props[ii] != null ? props[ii].GetValue(Entity) : String.Empty)
```

and now your `handleNullProps` method becomes unnecessary.

**Edit**

Since you're trying Extension Methods, you could use them to get your values anyway like this

```
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, iCols).Select(ii => props[ii].GetValueOrDefault(Entity))
```

and let the method be defined like this

```
public static object GetValueOrDefault(this object s, object entity)
{
    if (s == null)
        return string.Empty;
    else
        return s.GetValue(entity);
    }
}
```

keep in mind that I put `object` to both parameters because I don't know they proper types - set the correct types to both parameters and should work fine

the `OrDefault` part is inspired in one of the linq methods [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tks  I'm trying ExtensionMethods because this is a more clear and elegant way . But seems like that's a wrong way.  :(

Comment: it's not wrong, but you're not even reaching your extension method -. it's throwing an exception before that. Let me give you one update

Comment: That is ridiculously simple and awesome, Why I don't think about it ? Very tks. you're great

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez if  this helped you please consider to set this answer as correct

Comment: I'm doing tests now... after that be sure I set as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is null in your case.

If it's the `Entity` then you should filter it out before:

```
foreach (var Entity in EntitySet.Where(e=>e != null))
```

If it's the `props[ii]` then `.Select(ii => props[ii]?.GetValue(Entity)` should do it.
And You can filter them out after wards the same way as before.
Your code can become:

```
foreach (var Entity in EntitySet.Where(e => e != null))
{
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, iCols)
        .Select(ii => props[ii]?.GetValue(Entity)).Where(v => v !=  null);

    // .... write in the sheet
}
```

**Update:** if it's `props[ii]` then i suggest that you filter it beofre:

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = FieldsToExport(EntitySet.AsQueryable()).Where(p=>p!=null).ToList();
```

And the whole code can become simpler anyway:

```
var values = props.Select(p=>p.GetValue(Entity)).Where(v => v !=  null);
```

Comment: The null is at props[ii], it represents a field on a record (Entity), I need to export all table even null values.

Comment: Tks for your help, null values must be exported to. I can't pass  four columns for record 1 and 5 for record 2, all records must contain the same columns. I'm trying ExtensionMethods because this is a more clear and elegant way . But seems like that's a wrong way.